# Why doesn't string_view disallow construction from string temporaries?

Tags: c++, c++17

`string` has a conversion operator to `string_view`; it constructs a `string_view` that points into the `string`'s buffer.  If this is invoked on a temporary `string` object, the `string_view` object will become invalidated due to the dangling pointer very quickly.

Why doesn't `string` disallow this conversion?  It could do so with two conversion operators:

```
operator string_view() const & { /* ... */ }
operator string_view() && = delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `string_view` from a temporary is often safe, and it is too useful to disallow.

Recall that the lifetime of a temporary object extends for as long as the full-expression containing it is being evaluated.  This is particularly relevant when `string_view` is used as a function argument.  Consider the case of these two functions:

```
std::string GetFoo() { /* ... */ }
void SetBar(std::string_view value) {
  // code that uses value's contents, possibly copying it into a new
  // buffer, but which does not save the string_view for later access
}
```

Given these functions, it is completely safe to call

```
SetBar(GetFoo());
```

because the `string_view` representing the temporary string will be valid for the duration of `SetBar()`.

`string_view` as a parameter type is one of its most important use cases.  Its ease of use is directly related to the fact that `SetBar()` can be passed any `string` or `char*`.  Disallowing conversion of temporary `string`s into `string_view` would significantly reduce its usefulness.

Comment: "too useful to disallow" is an unfounded personal position.
The conversion should be explicit. 
Allowing an implicit conversion is as bad as returning a raw pointer.

Comment: @RichardHodges: In my opinion, string_view's entire purpose is to make implicit conversions from either char* or std::string, as needed. Requiring explicit object creation ruins the whole point.

Comment: @ZanLynx saving those 8 keystrokes is going to cost a lot of software engineers a lot of hours tracking down random segfaults. I wish you luck.